# How can i show entries from two categories?

Tags: categories

is there an easy way to show two EE categories in a list?
let's say i have *agenda/C3* and *agenda/C9*

can i combine this to *agenda/C3&C9* (this obviously doesn't work)

(my problem: the C3 is a default category and should always be showed, even if you select another category)

cheers,
dave

Comment: Are you trying to list the entires for those categories or the categories themselves? Include your tag code for the one category so we can answer more specifically. Also are you attempting to get the category by it's label or do you know it's ID?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just read the answer you posted answer and you don't need PHP to do this.

In the template where you have your `{exp:channel:categories}` tag, change how the category URL is created so it just passes the category ID...

`<a href="{path=agenda}">` becomes `<a href="/agenda/{category_id}">`.

This will give you a URL that looks like `/agenda/9`.

Then in your channel:entries tag you use `category="9|{segment_2}"`.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried category="" in your channel?

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="{channels}" category="3|9" dynamic="yes"  }
```

http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/channel_entries.html#category

You could also try low seg2cat
http://gotolow.com/addons/low-seg2cat/docs

> ...where n is the segment number. {segment_category_ids} will return
>   an inclusive stack of all found category ids, for example: 4&12.
>   {segment_category_ids_piped} will return an exclusive list: 4|12.

Answer (score 0):

this is how i solved it

separate category template starting with

```
<?php
$uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$pieces = explode("/", $uri);
$lastsegment = $pieces[4];
$catid = substr($lastsegment, 1);
?>
```

and then the tag

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="agenda" status="open" limit="50" category="9|<?php echo $catid ?>" orderby="entry_date" sort="asc" start_on="{current_time format='%Y-%m-%d 00:00'}" show_future_entries="yes"}
```

and php enabled on input,
9 is the category id that has to be showed by default

Comment: You're making this more complicated than it needs to be and you don't need PHP to accomplish this... see the answer I posted.